# Android tabwidget each tab text

Tags: android-tabhost

I have tabview like below, I want to change text all caps to:

> 1. Purchases
> 2. Recharge Amount

and also want to size to text.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fragment is coded correctly, have a look in /res/values/strings.xml. In there should be a list of strings, and you will be able to update their formatting there.

If you can't find them in there, check the fragment itself for the values.

As for text size, in the fragment itself you can add a value to the TextView element (or the element that is holding the header).

```
android:textSize="16dp"
```

Adding that will change the size of the font.